# Want to add top padding on annotation text in bar chart in Google Chart (Visualization)

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart, google-visualization

I am using Google Chart's bar graph chart. There are annotation for every bar at the top, inside of the bar and I want create more space (more than default) between bar top line and annotation text. I have not find any way to create top padding (or top margin) around annotation text.

Here is my code:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                [USER_AVERAGE, 'User Average', { role: 'style' }],
                ['SANDRA COOMBS', 8.6, '#008FBE'],
                ['STEVE ADAMS', 4.3, '#008FBE'],
            ]);

            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns([0, 1, 2,
                {
                    calc: "stringify",
                    sourceColumn: 1,
                    type: "string",
                    role: "annotation"
                }]);
            var options = {
                legend: {
                    position: 'none'
                },
                chartArea: { width: width, height: height, right: right },
                isStacked: true,
                orientation: orientation.orientation,
                fontSize: '12',
                fontName: 'OpenSans-Regular',
                hAxis: {
                    viewWindowMode: 'maximized',
                },
                vAxis: {
                    viewWindowMode: 'maximized',
                },
                animation: {
                    startup: true,
                    duration: 1500,
                    easing: 'out',
                },
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("averageDaysChart"));
            chart.draw(view.toDataTable(), options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are no config options for annotation padding, position, or the like...

however, you can move them manually on the chart's `'animationfinish'` event
but, a `MutationObserver` must be used,
because the chart will move them back on interactivity,
such as when you hover the column.

see following working snippet for an example of moving the annotations...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['USER_AVERAGE', 'User Average', { role: 'style' }],
      ['SANDRA COOMBS', 8.6, '#008FBE'],
      ['STEVE ADAMS', 4.3, '#008FBE'],
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, 2,
      {
          calc: "stringify",
          sourceColumn: 1,
          type: "string",
          role: "annotation"
      }]);
  var options = {
      legend: {
          position: 'none'
      },
      //chartArea: { width: width, height: height, right: right },
      isStacked: true,
      //orientation: orientation.orientation,
      fontSize: '12',
      fontName: 'OpenSans-Regular',
      hAxis: {
          viewWindowMode: 'maximized',
      },
      vAxis: {
          viewWindowMode: 'maximized',
      },
      animation: {
          startup: true,
          duration: 1500,
          easing: 'out',
      },
  };

  var container = document.getElementById("averageDaysChart");
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'animationfinish', function () {
    moveAnnotations();
    var observer = new MutationObserver(moveAnnotations);
    observer.observe(container, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });
  });

  var originalY = {};
  function moveAnnotations() {
    var labels = container.getElementsByTagName('text');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(labels, function(label) {
      if ((!isNaN(parseFloat(label.textContent))) && (label.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'middle')) {
        if (!originalY.hasOwnProperty(label.textContent)) {
          originalY[label.textContent] = parseFloat(label.getAttribute('y'));
        }
        label.setAttribute('y', originalY[label.textContent] + 20);
      }
    });
  }

  chart.draw(view.toDataTable(), options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="averageDaysChart"></div>
```

Comment: Done. Thanks a lot. You made my day, brother.

Answer (score 0):

No need for an animation hook or MutationObserver, just use good old fashioned CSS for this.

With Column and Bar charts, you only want to apply the "padding" to the annotation if it's placed within the bar itself. It's only placed inside the bar if the annotation text fits in the bar. When placed inside, it's given a white text color, so let's target that.

```
#averageDaysChart text[fill="#ffffff"] {
    transform: translateY(10px);
}
```